# How to combine three arrays and insert multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 3 arrays, and what I want to achieve is, using foreach loop, I want to insert multiple rows in to database.
Here are the codes with am trying.

```
$array1 = ('Hello First row', 'Hello Second Row', 'Hello third row', 'Hello Forth row');
$array2 = ('This going to be First row', 'This going to be Second Row', 'This going to bethird row', 'This going to beForth row');
$array3 = ('also the first row', 'also the Second Row', 'also the third row', 'also the Forth row');
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name(first, second, third) VALUES (:first, :second, :third)");
$stmt->execute(array(':first' => $array1, ':second' => $array2, ':third' => $array3));
```

PS: I tried to use foreach loop, right above the $stmt execute function, but that was not working as expected.! It created 12 rows in table. Which are suppose to be only 4.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$array1 = ('Hello First row', 'Hello Second Row', 'Hello third row', 'Hello Forth row');
$array2 = ('This going to be First row', 'This going to be Second Row', 'This going to bethird row', 'This going to beForth row');
$array3 = ('also the first row', 'also the Second Row', 'also the third row', 'also the Forth row');
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name(first, second, third) VALUES (:first, :second, :third)");

for($index=0; $index<count($array1); $index++) {
    $stmt->execute(array(':first' => $array1[$index], ':second' => $array2[$index], ':third' => $array3[$index]));
}
```